# Want to pass data variables to another site with curl /php

Tags: php, curl

i am trying to pass some variables on a examplereceiver.com/check.php from another site which is exampledeliver.com/check.php , i dont know why this does not work . ( $usr and $pass are both variables that i have )

```
<<this is exampledeliver code php>> 

    $url = 'http://examplereceiver.com/sec/check.php';
    $post_dat= array($usr,$pass);

    function post_data( $url, $post_dat)
    {
      $ch = curl_init();
      curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
      curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
      curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $post_dat);
      curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
      curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, 10);
      $content = curl_exec ($ch); // This returns HTML
      $info = curl_getinfo($ch);
      print_r($info);
      curl_close ($ch);
      return $content;
    } 

    post_data($url,$post_dat);
```

the receiving examplereceiver.com/check.php has this code too

```
<?php
    print_r($_POST);
?>
```

Comment: What does — not — work? Any error?

Comment: it does not print any values on $_POST , so there no transfer 
No errors i think !

Comment: Your `URL` is `http://examplereceiver.com/sec/check.php`. But you check on `http://examplereceiver.com/check.php`. Also this is an asynchronous action. You will — not — get an output like this. You want to write to a `file` instead.

Comment: yeah this was a typographical mistake there with the paths but what you mean i have to write it to a file first

Comment: Try `<?php
file_put_contents('test.txt', $_POST);
?>`. Then you will see, that content is written. But how do you want to refresh the browser. In the millisecond `cURL` comes in.

Comment: i just want to go to the deliver page , the deliver page send the data to the receiver and then use them again in a $_session

Comment: You can do that. I just want to proof you, that the `data` is received.

Answer (score -1):

The best solution is to write code that recieves the data and inserts it into the database and you can retrieve it from there

Comment: This is better suited as a comment. Or, you could re-write this to provide an actual useful answer.